# Spring jpa disable merge

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i want disable merge in jpa repository. It should only be possible to create new records and prohibit updating old ones. 
So, how to disable the update of records for the repository if i extends from `JpaRepository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Making your entity immutable can stop changes happening to managed entities and as a result no changes will be propagated within the transaction.
- However it does not stop hibernate updating the database record, if you passed immutable record with id assigned and it already exists in db.
- So I think you can look into `@PreUpdate` entity listener and throw exception. So if someone tries to update, it will throw exception and update will not happen.
- But the best way is to create service which hides the repository and
- Service does a `find` before `save` to avoid second point
- Make the entity immutable to make sure first point.

Comment: thanks, the service will exist anyway, but I want to make it impossible to save to the database itself (if someone try to use repository). I  also can set entity fields as updatable = false.

Comment: Yeah. True i forget that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is basically an immutable entity, remove setters from your entity and use  builders to create new entities.